# Meaning of "erstwhile" & "gone in the first cull of hereditary peers"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He didn't believe her. The last thing his **erstwhile** brother-in-law had
>   ever felt was affection for the man they'd all called 'Jemima's
>   unsuitable husband'. It was a matter of some satisfaction that
>   Peregrine had **gone in the first cull of hereditary peers**.

**Source** - Gagged & Bound

**Author** - Natasha Cooper

**My question** -

1. What is the meaning of "erstwhile" (marked in bold) here?
2. What is the meaning of "gone in the first cull of hereditary peers" (marked in bold)?

Comment: *erstwhile bro-in-law* means the bro-in-law, not anymore in his original characteristics.

Comment: *Erstwhile bro-in-law* is a much funnier phrase than *erstwhile brother-in-law*.  There's a rather large formality mismatch between *erstwhile* and *bro*.

Answer (score 1):

*...gone in the first cull of hereditary peers*.

Traditionally in the Westminster system, when a peer (Lord) died, his heir inherited the position.  This changed following an act of Parliament late last century, however as you can imagine the people in power weren't very enthusiastic about limiting their powers, so the change had to be implemented in stages.

It appears that the named 'Peregrine' was one of the Peers whose hereditary position was in the first batch to be removed.

*erstwhile*

As any dictionary will tell you, erstwhile = former, previous, ex- (etc).